# (C++)Parsing Pseudo-XML

Tags: c++, xml, parsing

I'm trying to learn more about C++, and I'm in the process of making a (pretty simple) 2D map editor. I currently have a system that works very well, but I'm trying to improve through the use of tags.

**What I want to accomplish**

I want to be able to load up a text file, and have it store all of the data I might need in a level (including but not limited to: tiles, backdrop, objects, player, etc). These text files will be generated by my map editor, so I have complete control over how they are created, and their structure. *Although this isn't a school project, I'm trying to learn more about C++, so I'd rather use as few dependencies as possible (I'm currently only using SFML, but I don't think that's relevant for this), hence why I'm not using an existing XML Parser.*

```
//Call to my parser
getTagContents("Resources/xmltester.txt", "mytag");
```

```
//
void getTagContents(std::string fileToBeParsedLocation, std::string tagName)
{
int lineNumberToFindTagName = 0;
int lineNumberToFindTagNameEnd = 0;

std::vector<int> tagsLine;
std::vector<int> tagsPos;
std::vector<std::string> tagContents;

std::string tempLine;


std::fstream fileToBeParsed(fileToBeParsedLocation);

if (fileToBeParsed.is_open())
{
    while (!fileToBeParsed.eof())
    {
        while (std::getline(fileToBeParsed, line))
        {
            //Opening tag
            if (line.find("<" + tagName + ">") == -1)
            {
                lineNumberToFindTagName++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::size_t pos = line.find("<" + tagName + ">");
                std::cout << "Found tag " << tagName << " opening at line " << lineNumberToFindTagName << " at position " << pos << std::endl;
                tagsLine.push_back(lineNumberToFindTagName);
                tagsPos.push_back(pos);
                lineNumberToFindTagName++;

                //Test
                //std::getline(fileToBeParsed, tempLine);
                //std::cout << tempLine;
                //This returns really strange values
            }

            //Closing tag
            if (line.find("</" + tagName + ">") == -1)
            {
                lineNumberToFindTagNameEnd++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::size_t pos = line.find("</" + tagName + ">");
                std::cout << "Found tag " << tagName << " closing at line " << lineNumberToFindTagNameEnd << " at position " << pos << std::endl;
                tagsLine.push_back(lineNumberToFindTagNameEnd);
                tagsPos.push_back(pos);
                lineNumberToFindTagNameEnd++;
            }
        }
    }


    //Size of tagContents will always be half of either tagsLine or tagsPos (it doesn't matter which)

    for (int i = 0; i < tagsPos.size()/2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tagsLine[i]; j++)
        {
            //I think this is where most of the stuff I need to add should go

        }
        std::getline(fileToBeParsed, tempLine);
        std::stringstream stream(tempLine);
        std::cout << "Line contents: " << tempLine << "<>" << std::endl;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < tagsPos.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << tagsLine[i] << "." << tagsPos[i] << std::endl;
}
getchar();
getchar();
}
```

**What The Issue Is**

This might be mostly due to my incompetence, but I have no idea how to use the fact that I know the tags' line and position value in order to read between them. It should be trivial, but I can't figure out a way to make sure I can read any amount of tags properly...

Any ideas? (And thanks in advance)

Comment: And how about the closing tag? Knowing the position of '>' of opening and '<' of closing tag you can read content between them with `get()` function of `fstream`. To set your cursour position on '>' character you can use `seekg()` function.

Comment: Personally I am not sure XML is the best choice here. Until you are more familiar with how the basic parsing functions work in C++ it might be better to create a much simpler format. Something that closely resembles how the data is stored in the game itself.

Comment: Amadeusz, I thought about an approach like that, but I'm concerned I won't be able to read more than one line. One of the pieces of data I'm trying to store is my map itself, and though I'll know after reading the file how big it is, it could potentially be massive (not sure what the hardware limitations might be, but I'm hoping it might even be as big as several hundred thousand on each side). 

If that's simply not possible though, I can try to find another method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. You're trying to implement an XML parser without knowing parsing techniques. This project can never end in anything else than a total failure.

What you need is an existing XML parser, and there are two variants of it, SAX-style parsing which reads the file in sequence, and DOM-style parsing which reads the file into a comprehensive data structure.

The most popular SAX-style parsing library for C (and C++) is expat. I'm not sure if it has an object-oriented C++ wrapper, but if not, if you truly know C++ you can implement that in less time than it takes to do your own XML parser.

If you need DOM-style parsing, one option would be to handle the events in a SAX-style parser and construct a parse tree. Another option would be to see if there are any DOM-style C/C++ parsing libraries. Probably C++ library would be a better choice, as DOM-style libraries are inherently object-oriented and you do want to use the full features of the C++ language for them.

To see more about the various approaches for parsing XML, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Programming_interfaces

The Simple API for XML means SAX and Document Object Model means DOM.

If you really do want to implement your own XML parser, better to study the prior art (i.e. SAX-based parsing and DOM-based parsing) first and decide which of these you want to have. Your prototype parser represents neither and franky doesn't look like a successful approach for parsing XML at all.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't think it is a good approach (just trying to learn here)? I figure that if I can figure out how to read from a certain position (which I already know), I can work out what to do with the data when I read it. Since I am making the files to be read, I can easily control the format. Thanks.

Comment: This is similar to the popular question of parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions. Yes, you can do that, but never in a way that is safe for all possible HTML/XML files. I guess if you control the format, the approach might be fine for a while but then when the need arises to expand the format you find yourself quickly stuck again. Consider the possibility that somebody edits the files with a text editor in a way which makes them unreadable by your hackish parser but readable by a proper XML parser. If you truly want to use the approach you're using, then perhaps somebody else can help.

Comment: While I'd like to be prepared for any event, if someone tampers with the files, that's sort of their fault, and for the sake of me learning how this works, is something that I'm going to choose to ignore. If you still think I shouldn't bother trying let me know; you might convince me :P

(Out of curiosity, how likely is it that someone messing with the files will produce something that XML can read, but I can't, if I'm trying to read everything between the tags?)